# Prove that the set $B = \{0,1\}^8$ forms a group

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Prove that the set $B = \{0,1\}^8$ forms a *group* under the composition operator: $g \circ f$ is defined by $(g \circ f)(x) = g(f(x))$

Comment: Please clarify with an example, by giving explicitly any element $f\in B$.

Answer (score 1):

It *doesn't* form a group! A general element doesn't have an inverse.

[This is on the assumption that by $\{ 0,1 \}^8$ you mean the set of functions $f : 8 \to \{ 0,1 \}$, where $8$ refers to an $8$-element set.]

Comment: I thought so however could you please elaborate on why? I'm slightly confused.

Comment: For a function to have an inverse under composition it must be bijective (in fact, 'having an inverse under composition' is often given as a definition of 'bijective'). But no function $f : 8 \to \{ 0,1 \}$ can be bijective because, by the pigeonhole principle, $f$ cannot be injective.

Comment: It's not clear that the binary operation is well-defined, either. How do you compose two elements of $\{0,1\}^8$?  Usually, when one considers a set of functions as a group, they are functions $A\to A$ for some set $A$.

Comment: @MJD: My logician brain interpreted $8 = \{ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 \}$ in which case it's possible to compose two such functions.

Comment: I considered that, but even if that's what's meant it's a strange question.

Comment: @MJD: Yup. Somewhere there's been a communication error, methinks.